# GitLab global post-receive server hook for all repositories not executed after CI job completion

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, git-post-receive

### Context

After setting up a GitLab server, GitLab runner CI, and creating a test-repository that completes a CI-job successfully, I was experiencing some difficulties in ensuring a `post-receive` script is completed after the CI is finished successfully on the test repository commit.

### MWE

The MWE does the complete deployment, and uploads a repository to the GitLab server and runs the CI on the repository. However, it is not yet generalised well, hence it has (at least) the following requirements: System: Ubuntu 20.04, Architecture:AMD64.

```
git clone git@github.com:Deployment-Oneliners/Self-host-GitLab-Server-and-Runner-CI.git
cd Self-host-GitLab-Server-and-Runner-CI
git checkout post-receive
rm -r test/libs/*
chmod +x install-bats-libs.sh
./install-bats-libs.sh
./install_gitlab.sh -s -r
./test.sh
./test/libs/bats/bin/bats test/test_post_receive.bats
```

One would expect the `post-receive` job to create a file on `/home/<your ubuntu username>/Desktop/helloworld.txt`. (Which it does not, I assume because the `post-receive` script is not ran.)

To uninstall the MWE completely, one can run: `./uninstall_gitlab.sh -y -h -r`.

### Issue

1. The documentation says

- For an installation from source is usually /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks.
- For Omnibus GitLab installs is usually /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks.

However, for the used deployment script, this is `/home/name/gitlab/data/gitlab-shell` instead. Hence, I assumed that `/home/name/gitlab/data/gitlab-shell/hooks` is the default hooks directory.

I tested this hypothesis by creating a `post-receive/post-receive` directory and script, ensured they were owned by the `gitlab-runner` user, and runnable, and making a new commit such that the CI would complete again. The `post-receive` script was not executed by GitLab.

Next, I logged into the docker and found the actual `gitlab-shell` folder using:

```
sudo docker ps -a
docker exec -t -i 0f17db17c212 /bin/bash
cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/
mkdir hooks
cd hooks
mkdir post-receive.d
cd post-receive.d
echo '#!/bin/bash' | tee post-receive
echo 'touch server_example_output.txt' | tee -a tee post-receive
chmod +x post-receive
```

and verified the `post-receive` script creates a file called: `example_output.txt` in the same folder as the script (since I can't reach out to the linux user from inside the docker). I did not know how to make the `post-receive` owned by `gitlab-runner` as the `chown` command did not work because it says the `gitlab-runner` user is not found. I assume this is because the root acount inside the docker is actually the `gitlab-runner` account. The content of the `post-receive` script inside the docker is:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch server_example_output.txt
```

and it was manually verified using: `./post-receive` which created the `example_output.txt` file. However, running the CI on a new commit did not result in the creation of that output file.

Additionally, I tried to create a `post-receive` script inside the docker for a particular repository . This was successful and I learned that the script is ran from the root of the directory, so if you write `touch output.txt` the file will not be created in `/hooks/output.txt`, but in the hashed `<long hash code>.git/` directory.

### Question

How can I ensure the GitLab `post-receive` script is executed after a repository commit is performed in the GitLab server? (Is there some gui/button in the GitLab server that allows one to test whether the `post-receive` script is found by GitLab and executable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was twofold:

1. I created the `post-receive` script inside the linux user, instead of inside the docker.
2. I was looking for the output of the `post-receive` script in the wrong location. I assumed that it would produce an output in the same directory as the script is located. But the `post-receive` script is called from the root of the `.git` directy, hence that is where the output is created.

Initially I tried to overcome the issue of 2 by using an absolute path, but issue 1 implied that the absolute path that I had chosen did not actually exist inside the Docker container. Therefore, no output was created, (and I was looking in the wrong place for that output on the Linux device, instead of in the Docker container).

The manual solution I found was:
First get the Docker container id with: `sudo docker ps -a`, which returned `... ca3ba74eb832 ...`. Then open the docker inside the terminal with:

```
sudo docker exec -t -i ca3ba74eb832 /bin/bash
cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/
mkdir hooks
cd hooks
mkdir post-receive.d
cd post-receive.d
nano post-receive
```

then enter:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch touch general_server_output.txt
```

and save the `post-receive` file. Then make it runnable with:

```
chmod +x post-receive
```

It was not required to make the `post-receive` owned by the `gitlab-runner` user, because the `root` user inside the Docker container is actually that user, so it was already owned by the `gitlab-runner` (even though inside the Docker container that user is called `root`).